# Eclipse Remote System Explorer and ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO

Tags: python, eclipse, raspberry-pi, pydev, remote-debugging

I followed the tutorial (https://sites.google.com/site/programmersnotebook/remote-development-of-python-scripts-on-raspberry-pi-with-eclipse) and I can succesfully connect to the server (in this case the raspberry pi) from the eclipse client (windows 7). When I run a simple python like

```
print 'hello'
```

everything works. However when I run the following

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def printFunction(channel):

    print("Button 1 pressed!")

    print("Note how the bouncetime affects the button press")

GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.RISING, callback=printFunction, bouncetime=300)

while True:

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.FALLING)

    print("Button 2 Pressed")

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.RISING)

    print("Button 2 Released")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I get the following

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7744)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.0.201408261926\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2086, in <module>
debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.0.201408261926\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1543, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\francis.reed\workspace\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\10.137.10.110\home\francis\raspiproj\test.py", line 1, in <module>
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```

note : RPi.GPIO is only installed on the server (raspberry pi) and not the eclipse client (windows 7).

Is there a way to run the script, and have all import statements look for modules on the server (rapsberry pi) and not the eclipse client (windows 7)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working...I think I had a few problems.  First, I was trying to run the remote debugging session incorrectly.  This link is a little more specific:
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Also, my host IP address had changed, so that was incorrect in the pydevd.settrace() command.

Start remote debugger, add a breakpoint in the code, then start your script running from the Remote Shell window in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and get the same problem. Didn't read the last part of the tutorial correctly. I am using eclipse in different environments and get used to hitting F11 to start debug anything, which is wrong in this case and causing the ImportError.

My notes to original tutorial

1. debug does not mean run debug (F11 key), but start debug server *Pydev->Start Debug Server* and then run the python script from ssh console on raspi. The rest is similar within the debug environment.
2. the same script on raspi will not run independently, if there is left the command *pydev.settrace('DebugServerAddress')* and the Debug server is not started. So after finishing of debugging this line need to be outcommented.
3. instead of copying eclipse libraries to raspi can be **pydevd** installed by running following commands on raspi:

`apt install python-pip`

`pip install pydevd`